# Flutter Gallery Image Fullscreen Zoomable

Tags: flutter, image, gallery, fullscreen, pinchzoom

I'm building a flutter app that displays products. Now, in the product details page I fetch product data along with product images as URLs using http package.

My question is what is the best way to represent product images to users? I have searched Google for a Flutter package similar or close to the web lightbox but couldn't find any.

Any advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In your detail page:

Show images using `ListView` in a `Image` widget with maybe 60x60 width/height as a thumbnail.

On click of a image -> Push a new page which has a swiper in it. While pushing you should provide the list of items and the currently selected one. Also later on check for `Hero` widget to have a smooth transition between those pages.

### Image full screen page:

Place a `PageView` widget. Use the provided list in the `itemBuilder` and `itemCount` parameters.
 It comes with gesture detection and animation between pages. In each of these pages use a `Image` widget to display the image as full size.

Since you have not provided any code sample, I won't be able to help you more but once you progress and have questions then it is better to ask with your current code.

Answer (score 0):

I will share a complete sample using photo_view package. In your *pubspec.yaml* file add

```
dependencies:
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
```

**Then the main idea is to have a widget displaying something like a list of urls** that you get for one product details (or anything else in your app).

The widget will display current image in a header, with a back button to pop the stack. You can swipe to display next and previous image.

```
class Gallery extends StatefulWidget {

  final List<String> urlImages;
  final int index;
  final PageController pageController;
  final Axis scrollDirection;

  Gallery({
    required this.urlImages,
    this.index = 0,
    this.scrollDirection = Axis.horizontal,
  }) : pageController = PageController(initialPage: index);

  @override
  State<Gallery> createState() => _GalleryState();
}

class _GalleryState extends State<Gallery> {
  late int currentIndex = widget.index;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  /// update ui header when user swipe
  void _onPageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: AppColors.primaryColorTheme,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          '${currentIndex + 1} / ${widget.urlImages.length}',
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        leading: IconButton( // back button here
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            // create the gallery itself
            child: PhotoViewGallery.builder(
              scrollPhysics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: widget.scrollDirection,
              pageController: widget.pageController,
              itemCount: widget.urlImages.length,
              backgroundDecoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white70),
              onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
              builder: _buildItem,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions _buildItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
    final String item = widget.urlImages[index];
    return PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
      imageProvider: NetworkImage(item), // we are using url so NetworkImage
      initialScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained,
      minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * (0.5 + index / 10),
      maxScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.covered * 4.1,
      heroAttributes: PhotoViewHeroAttributes(tag: item),
    );
  }
}
```

Finally, you have to start the widget in a new screen from your product list (eg if you have a link or a button "additionals images" or something like).

```
  ...

child: InkWell( // or use gesture detector as your convenience
onTap: () {
     Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Gallery(urlImages : ["https://picsum.photos/200", 
              "https://picsum.photos/202"])));
},
           ...
```

You get it :). Hope that it will give you the main idea to achieve it.